# How to use mapToItem inside my Custom Item? (QML, Qt)

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I am trying to use the [maptoItem()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method) function, it works when I use it inside the `main.qml` but not when used directly inside my `custom item.qml` and I have no idea why?

`main.qml`

```
Item{
    id:root_toggle
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
 //... code here Column Item etc that changes the y,x position of ToggleAbleItem
ToggleAbleItem{
                id:second_toggle_item

                Text {
                    id:fsdfsd
                    text: "text2"
                    color: "blue"
                    font.pixelSize: 24
                }
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    var l = second_toggle_item.mapToItem(root_toggle, 0, 0)
                    console.log(l)
                }

            }
  }
  //... code here
```

Console log correctly prints `[debug] expression for onCompleted (qrc:/main.qml:182)  - QPointF(0, 42)`

`ToggleAbleItem.qml`

```
Item{
id: id_toggleable_item
implicitHeight: childrenRect.height
implicitWidth: childrenRect.width
readonly property point absolute_position: id_toggleable_item.mapToItem(root_toggle, 0, 0) 

Component.onCompleted: {
      console.log(absolute_position)
    }

}
```

Console log prints wrong values `[debug] expression for onCompleted (qrc:/ToggleFunctionality/ToggleAbleItem.qml:53)  - QPointF(0, 0)`

Can someone explain to me why it is mapping one time correctly and the other time not?

I used the exact same item and id.

## EDIT 1:

The goal is not to use `parent` since it can be the 6th child etc...

I have also tried to set `property Item my_root_item: root_toggle` inside  `ToggleAbleItem.qml`  and then I tried it also on  `main.qml`

Comment: you shouldn't rely on ids from other files. `root_toggle` is an id from `main.qml` which you try to reference in `ToggleAbleItem.qml`. Either use a `property Item` in `ToggleAbleItem.qml` and set it on the `ToggleAbleItem` in `main.qml` or use the `parent` property to access it.

Comment: Another option would be to set the `absolute_position` property from within `main.qml` where the id `root_toggle` is actually located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is basically a matter of binding evaluation. When the `ToggleableItem` is created and the `absolutePosition` property is evaluated the positioning of the item has not been done yet and because the bound statement isn't connected to any geometry property of the Item that would trigger a reevaluation the property keeps its initial value of (0,0).

One solution would be to add the `toggleableItem.y` in front of the binding expression so that the binding is always reevaluated if the `y` property changes. Basically, make the binding dependent on a geometric property that changes when the item is re-positioned.

The other solution would be to create a function `absolutePositionFunc()` which gets called after the positioning is done whenever you need to get the absolute position.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        id: rootToggle
        anchors.fill: parent

        Column {
            ToggleableItem {
                id: toggleItem1
                rootItem: rootToggle
                color: "red"

                Component.onCompleted: console.log("toggle item #1", toggleItem1.mapToItem(rootToggle, 0, 0))
            }

            ToggleableItem {
                id: toggleItem2
                rootItem: rootToggle
                color: "green"

                Component.onCompleted: console.log("toggle item #2", toggleItem2.mapToItem(rootToggle, 0, 0))
            }

            onPositioningComplete: {
                console.log(toggleItem1.absolutePosition,
                            toggleItem1.absoultePositionFunc())
                console.log(toggleItem2.absolutePosition,
                            toggleItem2.absoultePositionFunc())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ToggleableItem.qml`

```
import QtQuick

Rectangle {
    id: toggleableItem
    required property Item rootItem
    readonly property point absolutePosition: {
        toggleableItem.y // geometric property in binding to trigger re-evaluation
        return toggleableItem.mapToItem(toggleableItem.rootItem, 0, 0)
    }

    function absolutePositionFunc() {
        return toggleableItem.mapToItem(toggleableItem.rootItem, 0, 0)
    }

    width: 100
    height: 40

    Component.onCompleted: console.log("absoulte position",
                                       toggleableItem.absolutePosition)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my comments on your question. This is the solution using the `parent` property. Again, don't use ids across different files.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        id: rootToggle
        anchors.fill: parent

        ToggleableItem {
            id: secondToggleItem
            x: 50
            y: 50

            Text {
                text: "text2"
                color: "blue"
                font.pixelSize: 24
            }

            Component.onCompleted: console.log(secondToggleItem.mapToItem(rootToggle, 0, 0))
        }
    }
}
```

`ToggleableItem.qml`

```
import QtQuick

Item {
    id: idToggleableItem
    implicitHeight: childrenRect.height
    implicitWidth: childrenRect.width

    readonly property point absolutePosition: idToggleableItem.mapToItem(parent, 0, 0)

    Component.onCompleted: console.log(idToggleableItem.absolutePosition)
}
```

Comment: Btw if I don't set `x` and `y` on the `ToggleableItem` I get `qml: QPointF(0, 0)
qml: QPointF(0, 0)` for both console outputs which is correct looking at your example. There is no additional positioning in the code you've shared.

Comment: Using `parent` as a solution will not work I want to map it to my `root` I tried `required property Item root_item` and then assigning it at my `main.qml` but this also doesn't work. I still thanked you for the help (because my question wasnt specific enough)

Answer (score 0):

I had to assign the value after completion inside the `Component.onCompleted()` function and then the value is no more 0. I also choosed the `mapFromItem()` function instead of the `mapToItem()` and called it from the root.

```
Component.onCompleted: {
      absolute_position = root_toggle.mapFromItem(id_toggleable_item, childrenRect.x,childrenRect.y);
}
```

I know it works but If anybody has an explanation for this so I can finally fully understand QML I would still be grateful!